# Textract cannot read a JpegImageFile (StringIO objects)

Tags: python, text-extraction, stringio

I suppose in-memory file-like objects are expected to behave like files. I am not able to get Textract to "read" a

```
<StringIO.StringIO instance at 0x05039EB8>
```

although the program runs fine if I save the JPEG file to disk and read in the normal course.

The jpeg file is being extracted from pdfs, per Ned Batchelder's excellent blog [Extracting JPGs from PDFs](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200712/extracting_jpgs_from_pdfs.html). Relevant code below:

```
type(jpg) --> str (on 2.7)
buff = StringIO.StringIO()
buff.write(jpg)
buff.seek(0)
type(buff) --> instance
print buff --><StringIO.StringIO instance at 0x05039EB8>
dt=Image.open(buff)
print dt --><PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=2630x597 at 0x58C2A90>
text=textract.process(dt)`
```

This line fails. Textract cannot read the `JpegImageFile`
If I do

```
text=textract.process(buff.getvalue())
```

I get an error: `must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str`

How do I get Textract to read from the in-memory file or streams?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution; in-memory files is not the way to deal with legacy code. Routing the jpg extract to a hard coded `tempfile` worked.

```
tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile
```

It is a bit tedious to write the data stream to a tempfile and textract.process it; I couldn't figure out the BytesIO/StringIO way topassing the byte stream to textract. According to Textract docs, it expects a file. updated workaround code snippet:

```
pdf = file('file name', "rb").read()

startmark = "\xff\xd8"
startfix = 0
endmark = "\xff\xd9"
endfix = 2
i = 0

njpg = 0
while True:
    istream = pdf.find("stream", i)
    if istream < 0:
        break
    istart = pdf.find(startmark, istream, istream+20)
    if istart < 0:
    i = istream+20
        continue
    iend = pdf.find("endstream", istart)
    if iend < 0:
        raise Exception("Didn't find end of stream!")
    iend = pdf.find(endmark, iend-20)
    if iend < 0:
        raise Exception("Didn't find end of JPG!")

    istart += startfix
    iend += endfix
    print "JPG %d from %d to %d" % (njpg, istart, iend)
    jpg = pdf[istart:iend]

    njpg += 1
    i = iend

import tempfile
temp=tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False,suffix='.jpg')
temp.write(jpg)
temp.close()
text=textract.process(temp.name)
print text
```

Info: Python 2.7 on Win7; forced UTF-8 encoding

```
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8').
```

Hope this helps someone, because `textract` is actually a great piece of code. The pdf to jpeg converter code is courtesy Ned Batchelder [Extracting JPGs from PDFs](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200712/extracting_jpgs_from_pdfs.html) (2007).